# OpenConnect with Apigility to answer with JWT

Tags: php, pdo, oauth-2.0, laminas-api-tools, openconnect

How do I implement OpenConnect with Apigility to be answered with a JWT type response?

The problem is that is pretty simple to add just OAuth2, just following Apigility's [documentation](https://apigility.org/documentation/auth/authentication-oauth2) (or [this one](http://robbramos.com/rest-api-apigility-doctrine-oauth2/) that's really great), but when it comes to get that JWT like the example bellow is not that easy to find documentation.

```
{
  "id": "394a71988caa6cc30601e43f5b6569d52cd7f6df",
  "jti": "394a71988caa6cc30601e43f5b6569d52cd7f6df",
  "iss": "issuer_id",
  "aud": "client_id",
  "sub": "user_id",
  "exp": 1483711650,
  "iat": 1483708050,
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "scope": "onescope twoscope"
}
```

So, this is more of an Q&A, since I haven't found it anywhere and took me almost 2 weeks to gather all the info myself, thought it would be useful to someone else.

Note that JWT comes in 3 parts:

```
HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE
```

The first 2 come in Base64, in which you can just use, the last one is a key generated for validation. (see [this](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/) for more details).

The solution will be bellow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add OpenConnect to the supported OAuth2 built-in Apigility so you'd get a [JWT](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/) as answer, that's what you should do:

First, add these lines to /config/autoload/global.php

```
    'zf-oauth2' => [
        'allow_implicit'  => true,
        'access_lifetime' => 28800,
        'enforce_state'   => true,
        'options' => [
            'use_jwt_access_tokens'             => true,
            'store_encrypted_token_string'      => true,
            'use_openid_connect'                => true,
            'issuer'                            => 'issueroftoken.com',
            'id_lifetime'                       => 28800,
            'www_realm'                         => 'Service',
            'token_param_name'                  => 'access_token',
            'token_bearer_header_name'          => 'Bearer',
            'require_exact_redirect_uri'        => true,
            'allow_credentials_in_request_body' => true,
            'allow_public_clients'              => true,
            'always_issue_new_refresh_token'    => true,
            'unset_refresh_token_after_use'     => true,
        ],
    ],
```

The lines that matter there are `use_jwt_access_tokens` and `use_openid_connect` which must be set to true and `issuer` that must be filled (I added my website's address). The rest can be removed if you don't want to change their [defaults](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2/blob/master/config/oauth2.local.php.dist).

Then you'd need to create this table (found this info [here](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/openid-connect/)):

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_public_keys (
  client_id            VARCHAR(80),
  public_key           VARCHAR(2000),
  private_key          VARCHAR(2000),
  encryption_algorithm VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'RS256'
)
```

This table will be used to store the one key for each client, that you should generate by running the command (found this one [here](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/)):

```
# private key
$ openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048

# public key
$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -pubout -out pubkey.pem
```

Then you should take the content of those files and fill `public_key` and `private_key` along with the `client_id`.

My access tokens were being generated at `oauth_access_tokens` because I am using implicit type grant (no `client_secret` on `oauth_clients` and the `allow_implicit` flag on global.php), so I needed to increase the `access_token` field, you may need to check how many chars the field(s) you're using have:

```
ALTER TABLE `oauth_access_tokens` CHANGE `access_token` `access_token` VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL;
```

That should be it! You should now be getting a JWT as an answer from Apigility!

Hope this helps.